# Powershell how to force numbers as text in export-csv

Tags: parsing, powershell, export-to-csv, text-mining

My script constructs an object by text-mining files and then outputs it as LookupTable.csv. The first column of the .CSV contains the second line read from a .TXT file. The second column contains the original name of the file.

The second line of each .TXT file is a numeric ID which is currently misinterpreted as a number. How do I force PowerShell to pass the value as is into the .CSV? Or why is the .CSV misinterpreting the values?

For example, the value "-696706651--001" appears as "-696706651--1", even though the 2nd line in the .TXT is "-696706651--001". It seems this mostly/only happens when the unique value I'm trying to extract has a "-" in front of it, i.e. "700111651--001" appears correctly as "700111651--001" in my output .CSV.

**SCRIPT**

```
# Construct an out-array to use for data export
$OutArray = @()

# Import CSV containing location of TXT files to search (the 2nd line is retrieved from each file).
$Files = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\PROJECTS\SearchDocs.csv' -Header ("TxtName","PdfName")

ForEach($file in $Files)
{
    # Look at second line of the text file and pass it to newName
    $newName = Get-Content -Path $file.TxtName | Select-Object -Index 1

    # suffix .pdf to newName
    $newName2 = $newName + ".pdf"

    # Rename the file using the second line found in the file
    Rename-Item $file.PdfName $newName2

    #Construct an object for the export
    $myobj = "" | Select "fileID","Title"

    #fill the object
    $myobj.fileID = $newName   # This value does not always match the text read
    $myobj.Title = $file.PdfName

    #Add the object to the out-array
    $outarray += $myobj

    #Wipe the object just to be sure
    $myobj = $null
}

#After the loop, export the array to CSV
$outarray | export-csv "C:\Data\PROJECTS\LookupTable.csv"
```

Comment: How do you know that it's treated as number? If you open it in text editor, is it correct? It might be that excel is looking at it wrong

Comment: Could you try this: $myobj.fileID = "'$newName" (double quote, single quote, $newName, double quote), the single quote being a way to force cell content as text.

Comment: @DavidBrabant: That works. It leaves the single quote in the front but it's easy to remove. Thanks!